# Listening Socket.io event works server's side but not client's side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am working on a student project, a dating website.
I recently tried to use Socket.io but I encounter a problem

I would like to emit an event when a user views a profile

Server side listening:
Update database

Client side listening:
display a notification

When I emit the event 'view user', I can listen to it on the server side, it works

But when I try to listen to on the client side, it does not work

Emit the event :

```
socket.emit('view user', userId, userTarget)
```

Listening to it on the server side :

```
export const listenView = (socket) => {
  socket.on('view user', (userId, userTarget) => {
    console.log(`${ userId } viewed ${ userTarget }`)
    //viewUser(userId, userTarget)
  })
}
```

Listening on the client side :

```
componentDidMount () {
  console.log('MOUNTED')
  socket.on('view user', (userId, userTarget) => {
    console.log(`test viewed listening ${ userId } views ${ userTarget }`)
  })
}
```

It works on the server side : `724688ca-a9a5-4863-ace8-99e541c63b8f viewed 53bdd4e0-10db-43dd-b57b-6efead866517`

But on the client side only `MOUNTED` is printed instead of

```
MOUNTED
test view listening 724688ca-a9a5-4863-ace8-99e541c63b8f viewed 53bdd4e0-10db-43dd-b57b-6efead866517
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you in advance !

EDIT: Socket is always the same, I checked the ID on the client side and on the server side and it's the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
To see the events on the client side I had to emit it from the server :

```
export const listenView = (socket) => {
  socket.on('view user', (userId, userTarget) => {
    console.log(`${ userId } viewed ${ userTarget }`)
    socket.emit('view user', userId, userTarget)
    //viewUser(userId, userTarget)
  })
}
```